# How to use my own local web server to run Laravel?

Tags: laravel, webserver

Though I'm famillar of how MVC works I'm a novice Laravel Dev.

After reading the installation [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3#server-requirements), and succesfully started it's server. (i'm not using homestead) I was wondering if i could use my own web server (easyphp) to run laravel localhost instead of it's own mini web server. Can I do that without running the command `php artisan serve`?

Comment: I just googled it and easyphp looks like  typical LAMP stack. You should be find to serve Laravel through it. Have you tried?

Comment: make `laravel/public` as root directory of server and it should work...

Comment: @AkshayKhale thanks it worked!

Comment: @James yes it will work but that's just the laravel mini web server not the easyphp!

Comment: @HardSpocker I was referring to whether you had tried running laravel through easyphp. It looks like you have figured it out now though

Answer (score 0):

You can run laravel anywhere, it's nothing special. Though as you would know you should redirect it's rootdirectory to / public which can be done by virtualization or using some htaccess file. Both are really easy to do and should work right away.